# problem to create a downloadable file in flask

Tags: python, flask, download

I want to create downloadable files and I did it.
But when I want to download it in a download manager, I cant Pause/Resume it and it has to download the whole file.

Here is my code :

```
@app.route('/Media/music/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Music(filename):
    return send_file('static//Media/music/'+filename, as_attachment=True)
```

|Flask and Python|

I would appreciate any help or reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to retrieve the [`Range` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22894873/1399491) if the browser is sending it and then open the byte range of the file and pass that to `send_file` as the file pointer:

```
partial_file = f.seek(start_of_byte_range)
...return send_file(partial_file, ....), 206
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376554/1399491

and make sure you respond with an HTTP 206 with the partial file range instead of the normal 200 or other HTTP code

[Range header info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range)

Here is a rough *untested* version of what this would look like:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/Media/music/<filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Music(filename):
    range_header = request.headers.get('Range')
    if range_header is not None:
        with open('static//Media/music/'+filename, 'rb') as f:
            partial_file = f.seek(range_header)
            return send_file(partial_file, as_attachment=True, conditional=True), 206
        raise Exception("Unknown exception")

    return send_file('static//Media/music/'+filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i am not a professional in Flask, could you please tell me what I should edit in my code.

Comment: @Revisto Sure, I can add some more snippets but you will need to tweak

Comment: definitely, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Revisto ok added some details hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks you so much